# Oracle join's order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql sentence.

```
select a.*,b.*,c.*
from a 
inner join b
on a.id=b.id
left join c 
on b.id=c.id
```

but I not konw it is execute inner join first .then create a temporary table such as temp .and finaly temp left join c.  inner join ,left join and right join do they have same level of execution.Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you try running it on some sample data, and see what the results are?

Comment: All right.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query describes the result set being produced.  When interpreting a query, the join order is from left to right.  So, in your query, the result set is the one produced by an inner join on a and b with that result being left joined to c.

You can add parentheses to avoid ambiguity:

```
from (a inner join
      b
      on a.id = b.id
     ) left join
     c 
     on b.id = c.id
```

But that is unnecessary.

That is *logically* how the query is processed.  The optimization engine can choose many different ways of executing the query, some of which might be pretty unrecognizable as relating to this particular query.  The only guarantee is what the result set looks like.

Comment: I see.Thank you very much!